# Creating a product array for Google Analytics ecommerce via GTM

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, enhanced-ecommerce

I have the following function to pass items from a shopping cart into the data layer and then on to Google Analytics through GTM.

No problem with the variables, those are all populating fine. **It's how I've tried to create the products array, it's not done correctly**. If I have more than one product in the cart, only the first product gets passed into the data layer.

You'll notice two events: sendTransaction and sendUpsell. That's because there's an option in the shopping cart to also make a personal donation on top of the products you're purchasing which gets added to the total transaction amount.

```
  function eCommerceTracker(){
    var storeId = "store_id"; 
    var personalGift = $('p#additional_donation').text().replace("$","").replace(/[,]/g, "").trim();
    var trackingCode = $('span#tracking_code').text().trim();

    var numItems = $("div.ShoppingCart [class*='ShoppingCartRow']").length; 

        eQuantity = [];
        transTotal = [];
        itemName = [];

        $("div.ShoppingCart [class*='ShoppingCartRow']").each(function(){
          eQuantity.push($(this).find("div.quantity-column").text().trim());
          itemName.push($(this).find("span.CartItemName").text().replace("'",""));
          transTotal.push($(this).find("div.price-column").text().replace("$","").replace(/[,]/g, "").trim());  
        });

        eTotal = $("div.ShoppingCart div.total-price-column:last").text().replace("$","").replace(/[,]/g, "").trim();

        for (var i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
          if(eQuantity[i] > 0){ 
            dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'sendTransaction',
            'ecommerce': {
                'purchase': {
                  'actionField': {
                    'id': trackingCode,
                    'affiliation': storeId,
                    'revenue': eTotal
                    },
                    'products': [{
                      'id': trackingCode,
                      'name': itemName,
                      'category': 'eCommerce',
                      'price': transTotal,
                      'brand': 'myBrand',
                      'quantity': eQuantity
                    }]    
                  }
                }
              });
            }
        }

        //Adding personal gift
        if(personalGift){
          dataLayer.push({
          'event': 'sendUpsell',
          'ecommerce': {
            'purchase': {
              'actionField': {
                'id': trackingCode, 
                'affiliation': storeId,
                'revenue': personalGift
                },
                'products': [{
                  'id': trackingCode,
                  'name': 'Personal Gift',
                  'category': 'Upsell',
                  'price': personalGift,
                  'brand': 'myBrand',
                  'quantity': '1'
                }]
              }
            }
          });
        }     
    }
```

Does anything look immediately wrong with what I've created here?

Comment: why not to make a single dataLayer push with an array of the products information in the products field?
something like 
dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'sendTransaction',
            'ecommerce': {
                'purchase': {
                    ...
                    'products': [prod1, prod2, ...]

Comment: Yes, you need to build the array before the pushing. In your case are you overwriting the last object. So in the dataLayer will remain the last one

Comment: How would I go about building the array before pushing it?